# How to fix laravel livewire issue with pagination?

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a table which show some record but when I choose page 2 from table pagination and then apply filter on it they still show page no 2 table. My query is when I change anything from filter, pagination need to be remove and by default show record related to status.

Answer (score 1):

after query function add this

```
 $this->resetPage();
```

Or can you add public function to input search same that

```
public function updatingInput(){
        $this->resetPage();
    }
```