# Laravel Pagination + Livewire: How to retain number of data per page

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-livewire

Wanted to get an idea on how to perform this task or my question.

I wanted to have a datatable where it retains the number of data per page and doesn't move data whenever there's changes.

Let's say I got 50 per page then I deleted two data on the first page which makes it 48. I clicked on page 2, the original first 2 data of page 2 was moved to the first page because of what I've deleted. What I wanted is that it shouldn't move and should stay on page 2. Then if I click on other pages, it should still retain first page 48, second page 50.

Hope you get my question.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73990410/9569941

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to achieve that result, I wouldn't know how. But I suggest as a workaround that you set a property on each item, and then hide or show the item according to that property. This way the pagination counter remains the same.

In your controller:

```
$my_query_results = $query->paginate(50);

$my_query_results->each(function ($item) {
    $item->visible = true||false; //check a condition here
});
```